# How to echo cURL Response from REST php

Tags: php, xml, curl

I newbie on PHP, REST and cURL. I'm try to build an application to do GET and POST request. I did some tutorials and read cURL documentations.
I did GET request and get some response but I could not get my actual need :)
Here is my code.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://ise.cisco.connect:9060/ers/config/portal';
$method = 'GET';

// headers and data (this is API dependent, some uses XML)
$headers = array(
'Accept: application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.identity.portal.2.0+xml'
);
$data = json_encode(array(
'firstName'=> 'John',
'lastName'=> 'Doe'
));
$username = 'sponsor';
$password = 'Password1';
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

switch($method)
{

case 'GET':
break;

case 'POST':
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
break;

case 'PUT':
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
break;

case 'DELETE':
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
break;
}

$response = curl_exec($handle);
$code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE );


echo $code;
print_r ($response);


?>
```

`CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` is working fine but I'm expecting also xml.

Also,

```
foreach( $response as $obj ):
            $output .= '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r($obj, true) ) . '</pre>';
        endforeach;
```

display anything and give warning as a

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

All `curl-getinfo` functions work well. How can I reach my actual xml data?

That's the `print_r($response)` output

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Set-Cookie: JSESSIONIDSSO=55B8651BB47863C99C8B0450C61A84E2; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1BD1E6EB0CF6ED2D4CA6FCF019216431; Path=/ers/; Secure; HttpOnly Pragma: no-cache Date: Sat, 11 Apr 2015 13:24:11 GMT Content-Type: application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.ers.searchresult.1.0+xml;charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 1880 Server:
```

Kind Regards

Comment: Instead of `foreach($response..` try a simple `echo $response`. Because $response should be a string.

Comment: @PKeidel it displays nothing

Comment: When you output data tlo your browser to be display as HTML, you should HTML encode it otherwise you pass it as HTML and if that HTML contains HTML tags that your browser can't display (because it does not know the meaning of these tags), the your browser won't display them. In that case, change the content-type of the response to plain text or encode the data as HTML first or use the view-source functionality of your browser. But most easy in this case is working with a step-debugger like xdebug. No more outputting code just for debugging.

Comment: @hakre Thanks a lot. I found it in view-source.